# Java Stream: How to change only first element of stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

There is an ArrayList:

```
 public void mainMethod() {
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.add("'+7913152','2020-05-25 00:00:25'");
     list.add("'8912345','2020-05-25 00:01:49'");
     list.add("'916952','2020-05-25 00:01:55'");
 }
```

and method which transforms a string:

```
 public String doTransform(String phone) {
     String correctNumber;
 ..... make some changes...
     return correctNumber;
 }


list.stream().forEach(line -> {
                Arrays.stream(line.split(","))... and what else?
```

How to take only first element of sub-stream (Arrays.stream) and pass it to transforming method? 
"doTransform()" method is implemented, so don't care about it. 
I just need to separate '+7913152', '8912345' and '916952', pass it to doTransform() and get an new List:

```
"'8913152','2020-05-25 00:00:25'"
"'8912345','2020-05-25 00:01:49'"
"'8916952','2020-05-25 00:01:55'"
```

Comment: Your question is modified, so please make sure desired output in one time.

Comment: What transformation rule turns `'+7913152'` into `'8913152'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
                            .map(s -> {
                                    String[] parts = s.split(",");
                                    String st = doTransform(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(parts[0].replace("'", ""))));
                                    return ("'" + st + "'") + "," + parts[1];
                                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("'+7913152','2020-05-25 00:00:25'");
        list.add("'8912345','2020-05-25 00:01:49'");
        list.add("'916952','2020-05-25 00:01:55'");

        List<String> result = list.stream()
                                    .map(s -> {
                                        String[] parts = s.split(",");
                                        String st = doTransform(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(parts[0].replace("'", ""))));
                                        return ("'" + st + "'") + "," + parts[1];
                                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Display
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static String doTransform(String phone) {
        return "x" + phone;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
'x7913152','2020-05-25 00:00:25'
'x8912345','2020-05-25 00:01:49'
'x916952','2020-05-25 00:01:55'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can split elements using `,` in only two parts (initial which need to be change and remaining String) using `limit` on split [String split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

```
List<String> list = list.stream()
  .map(input -> input.split(",", 2))
  .map(data -> String.join(",", doTransaform(data[0]), data[1]))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It can be helpful when your string has multiple commas `(,)` separated parts and will surely improve efficiency too.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that length of the phone no in string as e.g `"'+7913152','2020-05-25 00:00:25'"` will be `7` if it's more than that you are going the remove the rest numbers from the head and replace with `8` to make it valid number else if number length is less than `7` then you will simply append the `8`, **Note**: you can handle if the length of the number is like `3` or `4` etc.

```
 public class PlayWithStream {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add("'+7913152','2020-05-25 00:00:25'");
                list.add("'8912345','2020-05-25 00:01:49'");
                list.add("'916952','2020-05-25 00:01:55'");
      List<String> collect = list.stream()
                    .map(PlayWithStream::doTransform)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(collect);
        }
         public static String doTransform(String phone1) {
             String []a=phone1.split(",");
             String phone=a[0];

                 boolean flag2 = phone.substring(0, 1).matches("[8]");
                 String finaloutput="";
                 if(!flag2) {
                int len=phone.length();

                if(len>7) {
                    String sub=phone.substring(0,phone.length()-6);
                    String newStr=phone.replace(sub, "");
                    finaloutput="8".concat(newStr);

                }else {
                    finaloutput="8".concat(phone);
                }

            }
            return finaloutput+","+a[1];
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works,

```
List<String> collect = list.stream()
                .map(a -> a.replace(String.valueOf(a.charAt(1)), "2"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Not only replace with "2" . There may be more comlicated transforming . But It doesn't matter.

Comment: ```['212345','2020-05-25 00:00:25', '212345','2020-05-25 00:01:49', '212345','2020-05-25 00:01:55']``` This is output for me.